# How to create Lookup field in Visualforce page using Bootstrap Library

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how to create lookup field in viusalforce page using bootstrap library?
My use case is create contact record fields(LastName,AccountName and Lead Source).
For that I have created a page and it doest give the proper style for lookup field..
My VFP as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" >
  <head> 
    <title>Create New Contact</title>        
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.js, '/js/bootstrap.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.js, '/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.css, '/css/bootstrap.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


    <style type="text/css"><!-- Spacing for the Nav bar -->
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

</head>

<body>
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Bootstrap Page</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-form span3 pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Right Link</a></li>
            </span>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
            <h3>LastName </h3>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}" styleClass="form-control"  html-placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"  /><br/>
             <h3>Account name</h3>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.accountid}"   styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Enter Account Name"  /> <br/>
             <h3>Lead Source </h3>
            <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LeadSource}" styleClass="form-control"   /><br/>


            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" styleClass="btn btn-success" value="Create New Contact" />

        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

</body>

</apex:page>
```

The above page gives like
[image]

My expectation looks like
[image]

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Comment: All the info to do this would be HERE: http://blogforce9.blogspot.com/2013/10/auto-complete-visualforce-component-v2.html

Comment: @Eric I have seen the blog that you mentioned. But we have to install that package. I dont want to install any package in my project

Comment: +1 to Eric's comment especially as its an unmanaged package (so source code is included and can be modified after installation) and its also available in [Github to brows/download](https://github.com/Avinava/Autocomplete-Visualforce-Component-V2).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a simple solution with just a few lines of code you won't get it. A good lookup mechanism is internally not simple. But luckily thanks to the component mentioned by @eric the usage is simple.

But since there is a unmanaged package here

http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000009KusM

you can install it in a developer org and have a look at the full source code. And also deploy it without any package just using eclipse later.